# Disable SSL Requirement for dotnet/docker on MacOS

Tags: docker, ssl, visual-studio-mac

I am development an application in .Net Core on a Mac and the application is supported to run in docker. There are actually two services and one runs as expected but the other has this error on start up.

```
"@t":"2021-02-24T15:01:06.3407645Z","@m":"Unable to start Kestrel.","@i":"fc6a528d","@l":"Fatal","@x":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
```

I **DO NOT** want this application to run locally with SSL. Please do not answer with creating a self-signed certificate. I cannot find where to remove this requirement. I'm not even sure where this error is coming from, but I'm fairly certain it is not Visual Studio because I'm trying to run the application using `docker-compose up`. Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew all I had to do was break down and ask the question and the answer would appear.

My docker-compose file contained this under environment.

```
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+;
```